# Is it possible to have https://yourdomain.com on an App Engine site?

Tags: google-app-engine, https, dns

I know the Google App Engine [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#httpsapps) say you can only have HTTPS on your `foo.appspot.com` domain, not with a custom domain.

But is it possible (and safe) to host a custom domain somewhere else, and set it up to proxy all HTTPS requests to `https://foo.appspot.com`?

If so, how would you recommend setting it up? And would it be much slower, compared to using `https://foo.appspot.com` directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do this. It's secure if you trust your proxy and you use SSL from the proxy to the app. It will be noticeably slower, since there's a longer path between your user and your app. In addition, unless you get multiple proxies, all your traffic will have to go via a single global location, whereas the appspot domain is served from frontends all round the globe.